# How to use key value in apache spark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to create the key value pair RDD for the author and the book he has written.

The data set looks like this with the two tabs separating he books and the author and then by space for subsequent field.

```
Rowling, JK  two tabs Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets space (1998)   
             two tabs Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix space (2003)
```

Where two tabs are two tab spaces and space denote the single space .

My question is how do I map these two books to the single author in spark and create the RDD?

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried.

Comment: I am newbie to this , I tried to split the line such as author.map(line => line.split("\t+"))) but this is not working for this

Comment: Please do not just say "this is not working". What did you get, and what did you expect? Split on tabs will do _something_!

Comment: Do you have the author name only in the first row? Is that the problem? If so, please make this clear in the question. (The title should be more specific.) Thanks! If that is indeed the case, I'll come back with an answer, I'm just not sure yet if I understand correctly :).

Comment: Yes Author name is only in the first place.. what I am trying to achieve is key value pairs such as ( jk Rowling , Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets) and (jk Rowling ,Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix) .. some other post I got the info to use toe mapPartitions how ever I have no clue how to use it with python for spark RDD